Understanding the Matrix $V^T(VV^T)^{-1}V$ and Its Minimum Element
Question:
Hi everyone,
I've been working with the matrix $M=V^T(VV^T)^{-1}V$, where $V$ is a $2\times n$ matrix with columns being 2D vectors $v_i$ whose barycenter $\frac{1}{n} \sum_jv_j$ is at the origin. I'm trying to understand the properties of this matrix.
In particular, let $\displaystyle m=\min_{i,j}M_{i,j} + \frac{1}{n}$, i.e. the minimum element in $M$ plus $1/n$.  Is there a lower bound which is about $-0.5$ for all $m$ belonging to different $M$? If not, can we construct an $M$ s.t. $m$ is smaller than $-0.5$, maybe around $-1$? I care about this question because it's related to some properties (non-negativity in particular) of the affine generalized barycentric coordinate used in CAGD.
Observations:
$V^T(VV^T)^{-1}V$ is an orthogonal projector, because it's symmetric and idempotent. Also $V^T(VV^T)^{-1}V=V^\dagger V$ where $V^\dagger$ stands for the pseudo-inverse.
My try: I've done some numerical experiments, and $m$ is never lower than $-0.5$. Below is my matlab code.
% Number of iterations
for i = 1 : 10
    % Number of vectors
    n = 60;

    % Generate a 2 x n matrix of random 2D vectors
    V = rand(2, n);

    % Compute the centroid of the vectors
    center = zeros(2, 1);
    for j = 1 : n
        center = center + V(:, j);
    end
    center = center / n;

    % Center the vectors by subtracting the centroid
    for j = 1 : n
        V(:, j) = V(:, j) - center;
    end

    % Compute the inverse of the Gram matrix
    VVstarInv = inv(V * V');

    % Compute the minimum element in V^*(VV^*)^-1V
    m = getMinV(V, VVstarInv, n);
    disp(m);
end

% Function to compute the minimum element in V^*(VV^*)^-1V
function [m] = getMinV(V, VVstarInv, n)
    A = V' * VVstarInv * V;
    m = min(A, [], "all") + 1/n;
end

Update: I managed to prove that $m\geq -1$, but I'm still seeking for better results(e.g., $m\geq -0.5$), or an example of $M$ s.t. the corresponding $m$ is around $-1$. I'll illustrate the main ideas below.
As I said before, this problem has a barycentric coordinate background. So we consider it in a geometric way. Given a vector $x$ in the convexhull of $v_1,...,v_n$, consider the barycentric coordinate of $x$ with the minimal $l^2$ norm:
$$
\text{argmin } ||a||
$$
s.t. $\sum_j a_j v_j=x, \sum a_j=1$, where I used $a_j$ for the $j$-th coordinate of $a$ under the standard basis $e_1, ..., e_n$.
As a matter of fact, $a$ has an analytic solution, i.e., $a=V^{\dagger}x+\frac{1}{n}\mathbf{1}$, where $\mathbf{1}=e_1+...+e_n$. We then plug in $x=v_j=Ve_j$, getting $a=V^{\dagger}Ve_j+\frac{1}{n}\mathbf{1}$. Remember that $a$ is the barycenter coordinate of $x$ with the minimal norm, and that $x=v_j$ has another valid barycenter coordinate $e_j$, we get $||a||\leq ||e_j||=1$, thus $|a_i|\leq 1$ for all $i$.
However, $a_i=\langle e_i,a\rangle=\langle e_i,V^{\dagger}Ve_j+\frac{1}{n}\mathbf{1}\rangle=e_i^T V^{\dagger}Ve_j + \frac{1}{n}=M_{i,j}+\frac{1}{n}$. Thus $|a_i|\leq 1$ implies $a_i \geq -1$, i.e., $M_{i,j}+\frac{1}{n}\geq -1$. Because we can choose $i,j$ arbitrarily, we know that $m=\min_{i,j}M_{i,j} + \frac{1}{n}\geq-1$. Q.E.D.

Did you notice that $M V = V$ and $V^\intercal M = V^\intercal$? This means that the eigenvalues of $M$ are all 1, yes? And that $M$ is symmetric.

@JAlex I suppose you mean $MV^\dagger=V^\dagger$ and $VM=V$ because $M=V^\dagger V$ and these are two basic properties of the pseudo inverse? But from that I can only get that two eigenvalues of $M$ are $1$ because $V^\dagger$ is an $n\times 2$ matrix. Another eigenvalue of $M$ is $0$ because $M (e_1+...+e_n)=V^\dagger(v_1+...+v_n)=0$, where I used the assumption that the barycenter of $v_1,...,v_n$ is $0$.

By the way, we have the eigenvalues of $M$ can only be $0,1$ because $M^2=M$ ($M$ is a projection).

The question requires $AA^T$ invertible, which is equivalent to requiring $rank(A)=2$, so $n$ should be at least $3$.
Now we give the exact bound: the minimum element of $M$ is $-\frac{1}{3}$ for $n=3$ and $-\frac{1}{2}$ for $n\ge 4$.
Denote the minimum element by $m$. Firstly for all $n$ we prove $m \ge -\frac{1}{2}$. Let $V=OPQ$ be the SVD decomposition, which $O,Q$ are orthogonal matrices of order $2,n$ respectively. We have an expression for $M$:
$$
M=V^T (VV^T)^{-1} V=Q^TP^TO^T(OPP^TO)^{-1}OPQ=Q^T\pmatrix{I&0\\0&0}Q
$$
Denote $Q=(q_{ij})$. The elements of $M$ are in the form $q_{1i}q_{1j}+q_{2i}q_{2j}$. Without loss of generality, assume $m=q_{11}q_{12}+q_{21}q_{22}$ (If $i=j$ then $m\ge0$ already). The rest is pure geometry. Denote $v_1,v_2$ the first two columns of $Q$, $a=(q_{12},q_{22},0,...,0)^T$, $b$ is the projection of $a$ onto $v_2$. (that is $b=tv_2, b\perp a-b$) Then
$$m^2=\langle a,v_1 \rangle^2\le|a|^2-|b|^2=|b||v_2|-|b|^2\le\frac{1}{4}
$$
so $m\ge -\frac{1}{2}$. When $n\ge 4$ the minimum can be achieved: $V=\pmatrix{\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}&0&0&\cdots\\\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&0&0&\cdots}$
When $n=3$ things become interesting: the minimum is always $-\frac{1}{3}$ no matter what $V$ we choose. As above, let $V=OPQ$ the SVD decomposition and write $Q=\pmatrix{a&b&-a-b\\c&d&-c-d\\e&f&g}$ (the sum of first two rows are zero because the sum of rows of $V$ are required to be zero). Now we have a system of equations:
$$
2a^2+2b^2+2ab=1\\
2c^2+2d^2+2cd=1\\
2ac+2bd+ad+bc=0
$$
Wolfram shows that $ab+cd$, the $(1,2)$-entry of $M$, is always $-\frac{1}{3}$. (However I don't know the details which may be related to some algebraic geometry) The minimum can be achieved: $V=\pmatrix{\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}&-\frac{1}{\sqrt 6}&-\frac{1}{\sqrt 6}\\0&-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}&\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}}$

Hi PureRun89, thank you for your answer. I didn't follow why $\langle a, v_1 \rangle^2 \leq |a|^2-|b|^2$, would you mind providing more details? I am not sure how $a$ relates to $v_1$ and $v_2$.

And the first component of $a$ should have been $q_{1,2}$ I guess? Is it a typo?

@cxh007 you are right! I’ll fix the typo soon. About the first question, let $c$ be the projection of $a$ onto $v_1$, then $|c|^2=\langle a,v_1 \rangle^2$ because $|v_1|=1$. We know $|a|^2$ is the sum of squares of norms of each vector that $a$ projected onto $v_i$ (this may be called some generalized pythagorean theorem),so $|a|^2=|b|^2+|c|^2+…$ (… are squares) so we get the result.

Wonderful! Another question, why does $|a|^2-|b|^2=|b||v_2|-|b|^2$? This means $|a|^2=|b|$ but I am unable to see it.

@cxh007 this one is nothing but pure geometry. Just notice that $a$ is the projection of $v_2$ onto $a$. (More detailed: if the angle between $a$ and $b$ is $t$, then $|a|=cos(t)$ and $|b|=|a|cos(t)$)

Oh, $v_2 - a$ is orthogonal to $a$ because of the way $a$ is defined, so $a$ is the projection of $v_2$ onto $a$, and thus $a=\cos t$. How brilliant!
